# What is the point of the lilypad in the Temple of Droplets?

Tags: zelda-the-minish-cap

I'm watching a playthrough of the Minish Cap. In Deepwood shrine there is a lilypad, and you use the gust jar with it to move around on water. This is before you have the flippers, so you can't yet swim.

In the temple of droplets, there is also a lilypad which you can take around most of the dungeon. However, at this point you already have the flippers so I can't understand why you need the lilypad. Maybe this would be more obvious to someone actually playing the game, I couldn't work it out from the playthrough I was watching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only get out of the water when there is shallow water.  As such, any land area that *doesn't* have shallow water needs the lily pad in order to reach it.

Comment: Aha thank you. Totally obvious to someone playing the game and difficult to work out from a video!